# Range of 3 month to 2 date pickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

i have 2 input type date one is the start date the other one is the end date but i want to make a range of 3 month. For example if a user choses the start date as 12/09/2018 the second datepicker should only allow him to choose 12/12/2018.
Any idea how to do it?

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="Sdate" ><strong style=" color:DarkSlateBlue" > Start date </strong></label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="sdate" name="startdate" required>
    </div>

 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Edate"><strong style=" color:DarkSlateBlue" ;> End date </strong>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="edate" name="enddate" required>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is the limit "3month" not change?

Comment: yes 3 month always

Comment: Then why did you try to add new date picker. You can calclate date using js and you can add label to show last date

Comment: no 3 month maximum range but he can choose less than  3 month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the answer as you expected

```
var date_input =document.getElementById('sdate');
date_input.onchange = function(){
   var selecteddate = new Date(this.value);
   var nexdate=1000*60*60*24*30;   //30 day count 
   document.getElementById('edate').max = new Date((selecteddate.getTime()+(nexdate)) - selecteddate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000).toISOString().split("T")[0];
}
```

Example here [Code pen](https://codepen.io/udarakasun/pen/xajgVN)

Answer (score 1):

please use below code

```
$("#sdate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var date = $(this).val();
            $("#edate").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date(date ).getDate() + 90);
        }
    });
```

Comment: yes,Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at JavaScript.js:2

Comment: You shold include jquerydate picker js and cs

Comment: Please include below line of code in <head> section

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

After select start date, change Min Date and Max Date of End Date,

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( { minDate:  Date(2018, 9,12), maxDate: new Date(2018, 10,12) });
```